# Do Postback on the click of jQuery dialog button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, dialog

I have an asp.net button control on the page.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinishReceiving" runat="server" Text="Finished Receiving" Width="168px"
                                    OnClick="btnFinishReceiving_Click" />
```

on the click of it I am opening a dialog box.

```
$("#<%= btnFinishReceiving.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $("[id*='ConfirmDialog']").dialog('open');

        });

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[id*='ConfirmDialog']").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    return true;
                },
                "No": function() {
                    return ValidateClientInfo();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Issue is : As soon as I click on the button, dialog box come up and page got postback. I want to postback the page once user clicks on a button in dialog box.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your form's "onSubmit" function return false.

UPDATE: To be extra sure, event.preventDefault(); will also stop any default behavior at that time, such as a form submit.

Comment: These won't work -- the problem is the javascript which .net emits.

Answer (score 0):

The onClick function in the asp:button is being invoked at the same time as the JavaScript onClick.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt is right, you've to modify your js function attached to the asp.net button.

```
$("#<%= btnFinishReceiving.ClientID %>").click(function(evt) {
    $("[id*='ConfirmDialog']").dialog('open');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

This should prevent the immediate postback, anyway I think this approach will not reach your expectations: the "return true;" inside the function of "Yes" button will not raise the original postback function provided by the asp.Button.

Take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570329/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-repeater/1579057) for a better explanation (ignoring the fact it's used in a repeater, the same approach could be used in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Mark-up:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinishReceiving" runat="server" Text="Finished Receiving" Width="168px"
OnClick="btnFinishReceiving_Click" OnClientClick="return openDialog();" />
```

JS:

```
function openDialog() {
   $("[id*='ConfirmDialog']").dialog('open');
   return false;
}
```