# jquery dialog and asp.net dynamic linkbutton

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I Have a gridview which has a row that contains LinkButtons that were added dynamically.
when these LinkButtons are clicked I need to show a confirmation dialog.
I tried to work as suggested in this post:
[JQuery DIalog and ASP.NET Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570329/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-repeater/1579057#1579057)
but it doesn't work, the postBackReference doesn't contain the right ID (it ignores the placeholder)
this is my code:

```
GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   //some code here

   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.Text = "something";
   lb.ID = "someId";
   string postBackReference = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lb, string.Empty);
   lb.OnClientClick = "javascript: showConf(function(){"+ postBackReference  +"});return false;";

   TableCell cell = new TableCell();
   cell.Controls.Add(lb);
   e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Found It! Should have used the RowDataBound event instead (for registering my JS function with the asp.net __doPostback)

Comment: I see what you mean. Regardless of whether you do it on `OnRowDataBound` or `OnRowCreated` I would add an extra parameter to the `showConfirmation` function with your **own** id so that you don't have to parse the server-side id at all to know on which record you are operating. I put some details on the comments section of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a solution that worked for me:
Basically I worked according to the solution in this post:
[JQuery DIalog and ASP.NET Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570329/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-repeater/1579057#1579057)
The only difference was that I had to use the RowCreated Event for adding my dynamic LinkButtons and RowDataBound Event for registering my client function (otherwise the original __doPostBack wouldn't get the ID param correctly (as if it ignores the fact that it is in a place holder)).
So my code behind looks like this now:

```
GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   //some code here

   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.Text = "something";
   lb.ID = "someId";

   TableCell cell = new TableCell();
   cell.Controls.Add(lb);
   e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

and:

```
GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   //some code here

   LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("someId") as LinkButton;
   string postBackReference = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lb, string.Empty);
   lb.OnClientClick = "javascript: showConf(function(){"+ postBackReference  +"});return false;";

}
```

client function- showConf and markup stay as they were.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As soon as you are able, be sure and mark your answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's the role of JQuery for your scenario. I imagine you want to show some sort of fancy confirmation box, if you provide the details I'll provide a more concrete answer, but for now, this is how is done with pure javascript:

```
GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

   LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
   lb.Text = "something";
   lb.ID = "someId";
   lb.OnClientClick = "javascript: return confirm('Are you sure that you want to do this and that?'); ";

   TableCell cell = new TableCell();
   cell.Controls.Add(lb);
   e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

**UPDATE** - Try something like this for the JQuery UI approach

1. have a div with id="dialog-confirm" in your markup as so:

   ```
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="" ></div>
   ```
2. Define a javascript function called showConfirmation as so:

   ```
    function showConfirmation(confirmationMessage)
    {
         $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("destroy");
         $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
           resizable: false,
           height:140,
           title: confirmationMessage,
           modal: true,
           buttons: {
               "Yes": function() {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                   __doPostBack(linkItemID, '');//will cause postback
               },
               Cancel: function() {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
           }
       });
    return false; //it will never postback
    }
   ```
3. Now your code behind should look like this:

   ```
    GridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
       lb.Text = "something";
       lb.ID = "someId";
       lb.OnClientClick = "return showConfirmation('Are you sure you want to do this and that?','"+lb.ID+"'); ";
       TableCell cell = new TableCell();
       cell.Controls.Add(lb);
       e.Row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
   ```

Note: Code above hasn't been tested but that should be very very close to what you need.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say, I want to use jquery-ui dialog

Comment: just replace the return confirm with a function that shows jquery ui dialog.

Comment: Thanks lcarus and thiagoleite, but I don't think it will work since it won't stop the original __doPostBack generated by the ASP.Net from firing. So before the user will be able to choose a button, the postback will occur

Comment: @A.B.Cade: Yes, it will stop it because the javascript function returns false when the user clicks on the Cancel button on the dialog. Notice how OnClientClick has `return showConfirmation...` That's exactly the same way plain vanilla `confirm` works. If you don't want the postback at all under any circumstance, simply change `return true` for `return false` on the `Yes` button also, or remove both returns altogether and let the function reach the last line, which always returns false.

Comment: Thanks again lcarus, that was my first thought but it never worked for me. Apparently, the jquery dialog doesn't suspend the process. Does your code work for you ?

Comment: I didn't test and I can't do it now but will do so in a couple of hours (I have a couple of meetings to attend); however, I've done something similar before and it works just fine.

Comment: @A.B.Cade: I have update my answer and it works fine. I just tested. There were several issues with my initial approach with should have been obvious to me: 1. The click handler for the "Yes" button is already a different function altogether; therefore, the original code was never going to do a postback even though inside the handler I was returning true. At that point the `showConfirmation` had already returned false. 2. I needed to add `$('#dialog-confirm').dialog("destroy");` before reinstantiating a new dialog or I could have reused the initial instance.

Comment: Ah! now that you added the __doPostBack it can work, but not in my situation, because lb.ID won't put the right id. It should be the UniqueId but as long as I do anything in RowCreated Event it doesn't work, this is why I had to add the LinkButton in RowCreated but register the ShowConfirmation function in the RowDataBound Event (as I wrote in my comment to my own question). as soon as I'll be able to answer my own question I'll update the post. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @A.B.Cade: I thought you were generating dynamically the link button id. That's why I added another parameter to the `showConfirmation` function that takes the id you assign it on `OnRowCreated` event, and that's why  `__doPostBack` is receiving this dynamic id now, so that you can use `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` to get the unique id and do something with it. The whole thing feels a bit hacky to me but it's difficult to give a better recommendation without knowing the whole context.

Comment: You were right, I am generating the link button dynamically, but I'm not sure how to use the Request["__EVENTTARGET"] in this context. What I wanted to do is use the RowCommand (as I would usually). And I agree, The whole thing feels a bit hacky...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on Page_Load and add a watch for Request["__EVENTTARGET"] you'll see that it holds the actual ID that you assigned the linkbutton during RowCreated.