# Asp.Net Repeater - Call ItemCommand event through Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

What type of post back occurs when I create a repeater and put a button inside of it with the **CommandArgument** and **CommandName** properties set?

I'm needing to mimic this call to the server so I can have my own custom postback and end up within the **ItemCommand** event of the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterTest" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr onclick="DO A SPECIAL POSTBACK">
     ...
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to try and emulate the appropriate __doPostBack call. There are quite a few ways to achieve this so have a google around here is a good start http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cpguide/html/cpcongeneratingclient-sidejavascriptforpostback.asp

Answer (score 0):

In the repeater you should treat the OnItemCommand event. In the event you'll get the source and the command argument. But in your case, as it's not a control but a , you should do manually a __dopostback.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in GridView and had some problems with initiating the __doPostBack,
look at [jquery dialog and asp.net dynamic linkbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401795/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-dynamic-linkbutton)

you might also want to see 
[JQuery DIalog and ASP.NET Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570329/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-repeater/1579057#1579057)