# Confirmation dialog Box does not file itemCommand in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net 4.5 with c#.From repeater on delete command I want to show confirmation dialog box.If user Press "Yes" than delete that record.My delete logic is in "rep_ItemCommand" event.Here Is my Code

```
    <as:Pager ID="pgeImportedFiles" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" RepeaterControlID="rptImportFiledata" Visible="false" PageSize="10" DisplayPagerOption="Top">
        <RepeaterTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptdata" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptdata_ItemCommand" >
                <ItemTemplate>                            
                        <div >
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnDelete"   
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return showConfirmation('Are you sure You want to Delete this File?',this.id);"                                         
                                runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CssClass="EditBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>    
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </RepeaterTemplate>
    </as:Pager>

 protected void rptdata_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {   
   //logic for deleteing
 }
```

this javascript in js file and "divDialogMessage1" and "divAlertBox1" defined in this file

```
    $(divDialogMessage1).html(confirmationMessage,uniqueID){
     var result = false;
        $(divAlertBox1).dialog({
            title: "Confirmation",
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    __doPostBack(uniqueID);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $(divAlertBox1).dialog('open');
        return result;}
```

By this dialog is display on click on delete link and page also post back if select "yes" option.But rptdata_ItemCommand not firing.

Any solution for this?

Comment: what are you returning in `return result;`

Comment: here edit my post.Return false value in result

Answer (score 0):

Logic for deleting

```
protected void rptdata_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {   
   //logic for deleteing
    switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "edit":
                    MyEditFunction(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    MyDeleteFunction(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                    break;
            }
 }
```

Confirmation Message

Add OnItemDataBound="AddDeleteConfirmation" to your repeater mark up and the following code in the code behind

```
protected void AddDeleteConfirmation(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                // adds a confirmation javascript to ensure that deleting the template is really what the user wants.
                ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbnDelete")).Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')";
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I use simple java-script Confirmation Box My code is also working. But I am creating a custom Confirmation Box with different style and UI. For that by dialog Box return true or false can't return after press "Yes" or "No"

Comment: And By postBack event repeater ItemCommand not called. Only page Load event calling.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570329/jquery-dialog-and-asp-net-repeater
It is really important to know your entire page life cycle to be able to suggest where the problem can be